# How to add a multiselect checkbox filter on ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My application is using Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS.

I am trying to add a multiselect filter that would allow me to view only the selected items I chose on ng-repeat. For example, here is a small JSON data sample of what I am extracting:

```
[
    {
        "MarketName": "Farm1",
        "Bakedgoods" :"N",
        "Cheese":"Y",
        "Eggs":"N"
    },
    {
        "MarketName": "Farm2",
        "Bakedgoods" :"N",
        "Cheese":"Y",
        "Eggs":"N"
    },
    {
        "MarketName": "Farm3",
        "Bakedgoods" :"Y",
        "Cheese":"Y",
        "Eggs":"N"
    }
]
```

If I checked Baked Goods, I would only see Farm3 displayed on ng-repeat.

If I checked Cheese, I would see Farm1, Farm2, and Farm3 displayed on ng-repeat.

If I checked Baked Goods **and** Cheese, I would only see Farm3 displayed on ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:
http://plnkr.co/edit/F5K6BkJvGny2fuLLuPCm?p=preview

Comment: Only have to modify the filter work with non Boolean values​​, but with a string. I think it will not be difficult.

Comment: This is the example with string values in Market object like in your code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zVbAfaTKxmQUqVhihKQu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you need a searchkey to define with your object values.

like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="SearchKey.Bakedgoods" ng-true-value="Y" ng-false-value="N"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="SearchKey.Cheese" ng-true-value="Y" ng-false-value="N"/>

<div ng-repeat="farm in farms | filter:SearchKey">
  {{farm.MarketName}}
</div>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Thank you so much for your guys' help. I will be using Konstantin Krass' approach since it is very simple!!

Comment: At initialization, this approach has the wrong behavior. At the beginning of all visible elements, but after selection and deselecting checkboxes no element is displayed.

Comment: Oledje is right. You have to set the ng-false-value="" to display all elements, if no checkbox is selected

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwrLc/70/

Code:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.trueFalse = [
    {
        "Eggs":"N"
    },
    {
        "Eggs":"Y"
    }
    ];

  $scope.trueFalseForBakedGoods = [
    {
        "Bakedgoods":"N"
    },
    {
        "Bakedgoods":"Y"
    }
    ];

  $scope.list = [
    {
        "MarketName": "Farm1",
        "Bakedgoods" :"N",
        "Cheese":"Y",
        "Eggs":"N"
    },
    {
        "MarketName": "Farm2",
        "Bakedgoods" :"N",
        "Cheese":"Y",
        "Eggs":"N"
    },
    {
        "MarketName": "Farm3",
        "Bakedgoods" :"Y",
        "Cheese":"Y",
        "Eggs":"N"
    }
    ];

    $scope.$watch('searchBakedGoods', function() {
        $scope.searchEggs = null;
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use a scope function to as data source in ngRepeat. The scope function will check scope variables bound to checkboxes and filter out some items.